# I cannot get insert a value into a matrix field using pow function in JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, pow

**Hello I have an assignment to input values in a matrix with pow function where the row its on power of column.**
We should get the value of the field by getting the row number and powering to power of the column, for example if we are in row 3 and column 2 we should get as a value 9

So here is my code and I don't understand why do I get this error:
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMeFE.png)

```
   `public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = (int)(Math.random()*100) % 10;
        System.out.println(n);
        if(n == 0 || n == 10){
            System.out.println("The program needs a number between 1 and 10");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        //int [] myArray = new int[n];
        int [][] myMatrix = new int[n][n];

        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<=n; j++){
                int value = (int) Math.pow(i,j);
                myMatrix[i][j] = value;
                System.out.print(myMatrix[i][j] + "\t");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What about your trials?

Answer (score 0):

```
int [][] myMatrix = new int[n+1][n+1];
```

Because your loop ends at <=n

Comment: This is your solution if you need the value of `n` to the `n`th power to be the at the bottom-right corner of your array.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the for loops to this :

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
```

The default indexing in an array starts from 0 not 1 and last index is  length-1. If you are accessing an array of size n then its possible indexes are - 0,1,2....n-1.
If you try to access array/matrix of total rows n, its last index is n-1. your loop reads  index n and so the indexoutofbound error occurs.

Comment: This is your solution if you're OK with having `n-1` to the `n-1` power be at the bottom-right corner of your array.

Comment: Thats right. Focussing on the point how indexing works in array. Of course array size can be altered at per the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help I finally realized what I did wrong with your help

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                int value = (int) Math.pow((i+1),(j+1));
                System.out.print(value + "\t");
                myMatrix[i][j] = value;

            }
```

this is the edit I got

Best regards to all